# Mongoid - Assign Attributes Without Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, persistence

I have a `Rails 4.2.8` app that uses `Mongoid 5.2.0`. I want to update a record without it updating the database. Basically, I want to mimic `User.new(user_params)`, but instead for updating.

Now, `ActiveRecord` has the `assign_attributes` method, but the `Mongoid` version seems to update the database anyway! Is this a bug or is there another method that serves this purpose?

Comment: I am using Rails 5.1.3 and Mongoid 6.2.1. A newly instantiated Object can get a hash of attributes assigned while remaining a >.new_record?<  in my setup jfi.

Comment: Yes, that's for a new record. I want to update an existing record in memory without actually saving those changes to the database (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Ekkstein - works for me on newer Mongoid than the requester used.

Docs have a method `update_attributes` as seen on https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard and also `assign_attributes` works without saving.

If all that fails, try

`class User
  # apply attributes one by one
  def silly_update_attributes(attributes)
    attributes.each_pair do |k,v|
      self[k] = v
    end
  end
end`